# Saving a PhpSpreadSheet through button click

Tags: php, laravel, spreadsheet

I'm trying to get my Laravel app to download an excel file with [phpSpreadSheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) a continuation of PhpExcel. But so far I'm not having any luck with it. I first tried to make an Axios call through an onClick but that didn't work since JS is not allowed to save things. After that I tried to attach the button to a Laravel action this just opened an empty page.

I don't know if anyone here will be able to help me but I will remain hopeful

Comment: What do you mean by **JS is not allowed to save things**?

Comment: I looked online and somewhere I saw that JS couldn't save things on your computer because of security resasons

Comment: You are looking at it wrong, using axios you need to **trigger** the download, not perform the save

Comment: But that doesn't appear to be possible with this package. I have to use an Axios call to build up the file and then use a save function in the php to save it but but it should prompt me or at least save it locally but so far I have had no success getting either.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

First you need to set an endpoint in your routes to call it using ajax (axios in your case):

```
Route::get('spreadsheet/download',[
   'as' => 'spreadsheet.download', 
   'uses' => 'SpreadsheetController@download'
]);
```

In your controller:

```
public function download ()
{
    $fileContents = Storage::disk('local')->get($pathToTheFile);
    $response = Response::make($fileContents, 200);
    $response->header('Content-Type', Storage::disk('local')->mimeType($pathToTheFile));
    return $response;
}
```

In case you don't have the file you can save it to [php://output](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php):

```
public function download ()
{
    $writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, "Xlsx");
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.xlsx"');
    $writer->save("php://output");
}
```

Now you just need to call the endpoint `/spreadsheet/download` to start the download, but a normal `<a href="/spreadsheet/download">Download</a>` would work.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: But this is just to download a local file if I'm reading it right.

But I need to build the file first. and then save it like this: 
$writer->save('Product-Report.xlsx');

Comment: If the file doesn't already exist you just need to provide a resource directly to the response method, instead of creating it from the saved file.

Comment: So that would look something like this? 

    public function download ()
    {
    if (! empty($pathToTheFile)) {

    $fileContents = Storage::disk('local')->get($pathToTheFile);
    $response = Response::make($fileContents, 200);
    $response->header('Content-Type', Storage::disk('local')-
    >mimeType($path));
    return $response;
    } else {
    $fileContents = $writer->save('Product-Report.xlsx');
    $response = Response::make($fileContents, 200);
    $response->header('Content-Type', Storage::disk('local')-
    >mimeType($path));
    return $response;
    }
    }

Comment: @FerdivanderWoerd That example would be used if you already have the file saved on your server.

Comment: $fileContents = $writer->save('Product-Report.xlsx');

Would this then make it so that it downloads the file I just build?

Comment: @FerdivanderWoerd No, I've updated the answer in case you don't have the file saved

Comment: I tried your second answer and it appears to do something at least.
It gives a response to the axios call but it's just a bunch of random characters:

     PKñQK'¦P[Content_Types].xmlÍWÝNÂ0½÷)ÞVh\^*úuýÆ¶¶iËßÛûm $~7kõüì´9iãuUFKp¾0:a"î²tjT¡g {{êXäÔJFCÂ6àÙxt1|ÛXðµOX½çÜ§9TÒÇÆÆ/qøêfÜÊt.gÀ{Ýn§FÐ¡j6¾ ¾+DSéÂ³¬P¯K
¶O#¶ÀZ;aÒÚ²He@ã|©Õ/ÕÉ²"eÒE¸¡¹¬YøAA6%ø¥¼u ÏBUÆ[Ò½ò2¹(Cô¸FömæJÞ.ÌÍ¶M¡ýã'ø+ÜJ-¡¯3?wìõW²Ðmà©3Ös:ÙÔÉ)PàBñ½ì­Ú©qp¼ø~Ôè?*îÒn¢ñ¼Äcÿâ?ÒG+">®ø¸!â£OÄÇ-">îø]*F¨4ª R©J§
*¥*¨´ª R«J¯

Comment: @FerdivanderWoerd Don't use axios, try just typing the url on your browser

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Do you know more about PhpSpreadSheet? In case I run into any more problems.

Comment: @FerdivanderWoerd I actually didn't know the package before you asked about it

Comment: Okay, because whenever I download my file, that I filled with data I get the same random characters I got as the response before that. But if you don't know I might ask another question.

Comment: @FerdivanderWoerd But the random characters are inside the file? It might be a headers issue, I don't know what exact file format you want. You should change the content type header to fit your needs.

Comment: @FerdivanderWoerd the error is on this line header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.xls"');  add an "x" to end of file.xls to make it header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.xlsx"')

Comment: @Asur This answer helped me to download Excel file, I just changed header lines to: `header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'); header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.xlsx"');` and it works great!

Comment: @NekoLopez Yes it looks like `xls` is a legacy extension, I will update my answer thank you very much!