# How to avoid Excel "bad format error" when saving spreadsheet

Tags: phpspreadsheet

Using PHPSpreadsheet saving XLSX format works OK running the default code

```
$writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx($spreadsheet); 
$writer->save("filename.xlsx");
```

But if I want to have the user to select the target directory using

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="filename.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadSheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save('php://output');
```

The file saves OK but Excel 2016 does not want to open it. Excel returns the following error
[Excel Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLzTk.png)

I looked through all documentation and posts but cannot find the solution.

Thanks !

Edit: Just in case, this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45737485/saving-a-phpspreadsheet-through-button-click/45739107#45739107) does not work for me.

Edit 2: The sample provided Simple Download Xlsx works perfectly, but when doing a copy/paste for my spreadsheet, Chrome gives me a 
`Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream`

Edit 3: Used 
`ob_end_flush();` to clean any left over header in my code. 
The file now saves OK, but needs repair when opening in Excel. Why ?

Thanks

Comment: What triggers this php? is it an ajax call, a regular submit or other?

Comment: It was a regular submit, but the file had 2 blank lines after teh last ?> which triggered the error. (as explained in the phpspreadsheet recipes....)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Bug from PhpSpreadsheet.

When using 
`header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");`

i.e. compatibility mode for Excel, the file opens OK.